# Bounded Subsets of a Well-Ordered Set

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

A proof I'm reading relies on the following fact: Let $(J,\leq)$ be a well-ordered set, $A \subseteq J$ a subset, and suppose that there exists $i \in J$ such that $a < i$ for all $a \in A$. Then there exists $k < i$ such that $a \leq k$ for all $a \in A$.

I can't figure out how to prove this. $A$ must have a least upper bound because $J$ is well-ordered, but what stops this least upper bound from being $i$ itself?

Comment: Are you sure you're reading it correctly? Well-ordered sets have the least upper bound property (i.e. a bounded set has a smallest strict upper bound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed false without additional assumptions.  For instance, $A$ could be empty and $i$ could be the least element of $J$.  Or, $J$ could be $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, $A$ could be $\mathbb{N}$, and $i$ could be $\infty$.

Comment: You're totally right - this is making me think the proof is wrong. I'm working through Theorem 5.1 in Chapter 1 of Hilton/Stammbach's *A Course in Homological Algebra* (page 27 here: https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug//otherpapers//hilton-stammbach.pdf). Would you mind taking a look at the last two paragraphs of the proof, in particular the claims of the existence of elements $k$?

Comment: The point is that an element if $P_{(i)}=\bigoplus_{j<i}A_j$ can only have finitely many nonzero coordinates, so you can just take $k$ to be the largest coordinate that is nonzero.

Comment: Ah of course, that's exactly what I was missing. Thanks!